# Rails Active Record Instance Variables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, instance-variables

My questions is in regards to this AR and its instance variable @saved

```
 class PhoneNumber < ActiveRecord::Base
has_one :user
validates_presence_of :number

def self.create_phone_number( user, phone_hash )
    @new_phone = PhoneNumber.new(phone_hash)
    @user = user
    PhoneNumber.transaction do
        @user.phone_numbers << @new_phone
        @new_phone.save!
        @user.save!
    end
    @saved = true
    return  @new_phone
rescue ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid => invalid
    @saved = false
    return  @new_phone
end

def saved?
    @saved ||= false
end
 end
```

It is my understanding that the instance variables will keep their values through the existence of the instance.

When using this AR in my controller, saved? always returns false..

```
@phone_number = PhoneNumber.create_phone_number(@active_user, params[:phone_number])
puts "add_phone_number"
if @phone_number.saved? => always false
```

What am I missing in regards to these instance variables? Thank you

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you're using the instance variable @saved inside a class method, the @saved var then belongs to the class, not to its instances, so you cannot call it from an instance method like #saved?.

what you can do, is, at the top of the class add:

```
  attr_accessor :saved
```

and inside the create_phone_number method, replace:

```
  @saved = true
```

with:

```
  @new_phone.saved = true
```

then it should work

Comment: excellent, that was the problem. Thank you for clarifying this to me